# Debuggin C# In Jenkins and NUnit

Tags: c#-4.0, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nunit-console

I need starting a debugging project before jenkins start test Nunit,
is possible to do this?

I have a solution with 15 projects and I need to debugging all solution for do a test in nunit, if I don't start debugging the nunit all test return errors

Answer (score 1):

You can run your unit tests in jenkins by adding new target:

```
<target name="build-debug" description="Build and run tests">
    <echo message="Building the debug configuration" />
    <exec program="${msbuild}" commandline='"${rng-solution}" /v:m /nologo /property:WarningLevel=0 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Any CPU"' />
    <echo message="Running unit tests" />
    <nunit2>
        <formatter type="Plain" />
        <formatter type="Xml" outputdir="${main-directory}\BuildResults\" usefile="true" extension=".xml"/>
        <test assemblyname="${main-directory}\Projects\MyUnitTests\bin\MyUnitTests.dll">
        </test>
    </nunit2>
</target>
```

This will run your Unit tests. thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use some of the pipeline plugins, they make you do steps one after all (each one have to be a different job, maybe in a shared workspace), and they can be made also conditional, reading the step before status.